# How do I Update Window Title text in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

When you visit Google, IE says something like *Google - Microsoft Internet Explorer*.  However, if you changed the address to, say, Stack Overflow, it would say something like *Stack Overflow - Microsoft Internet Explorer*.

So, how can I make a dynamic title bar that changes with a variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You set the `Form.Text`, using the current instance (which you access using `Me`):

```
Dim SomeVariable As String

SomeVariable = "Site 1 - My Application"
Me.Text = SomeVariable
```

For future reference, you can figure a lot of this out by clicking on the object you want to change things on in the **Designer** and then looking at the **Properties** window. In this case, you'd click on your main window and then looking at **Properties**, where you'd find the "Text" property. Changing it in the **Properties** window would change it in the **Designer** immediately when you type new text and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or move to another property.